# Converting a CSV column into a 1D list and then into a 2D list

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hope you are well,

I am fairly new in the python world and the coding world in general. I wanted to test python/panda's powers and the usefulness of making lists.

I have a column called 'Lines' in my csv file which reads like this:

| Lines |
| --- |
| A,B,C |
| A,D,C |
| B,C,D,E |
| A,B,C,D,E |
| C |
| C,D,E |

Which I converted to a 1D list (thanks to pandas):

```
lines = df['Lines']
print(lines):
['A,B,C', 'A,D,C', 'B,C,D,E', 'A,B,C,D,E', 'C', 'C,D,E']
```

Now I know there are a ton of tutorials out there but somehow none worked for me...
The output I am searching for would be something like this:

```
print(lines[0][1]):
B
print(lines[2][2]):
D
```

Is this something that is doable in python I wonder? Creating a 2D list based on multiple items in a specific CSV row?
Thanks for any help/resource provided!
Apologies in advance if the template provided is not useful/up-to-standards.

R.

Comment: lines[0] is a string.. not a list.. hence , when you access lines[0][1] it would return `,`

Comment: it makes sense, thanks for your comment! I will try to be more careful. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
lines = pd.array([i.split(",") for i in df['Lines'])
```

lines is now a 2D array. You can access elements like you wanted to.

```
>>> lines[0][1]
'B'
>>> lines[2][2]
'D'
```

Comment: Wonderful! Is that a list comprehension? Did not know the split method. Thanks so much for your help on this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
       Lines
0      A,B,C
1      A,D,C
2    B,C,D,E
3  A,B,C,D,E
4          C
5      C,D,E
```

Doing:

```
>>> df.Lines = df.Lines.str.split(',')
>>> print(df.Lines[0][1]):
B
>>> print(df.Lines[2][2]):
D
```